# Downloading an image, want to save to folder, check if file exists

Tags: python, file-io, download

So I have a recordset (sqlalchemy) of products that I am looping, and I want to download an image and save it to a folder.

If the folder doesn't exist, I want to create it.

Also, I want to first check if the image file exists in the folder.  **If it does, don't download just skip that row.**

```
/myscript.py
/images/
```

I want the images folder to be a folder in the same directory as my script file, wherever it may be stored.

I have so far:

```
q = session.query(products)

for p in q:
     if p.url:
          req = urllib2.Request(p.url)
          try:
                 response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
                 image = response.read()

                 ???
          except URLError e:
                 print e
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you can just use `urllib.urlretrieve` here:

```
import errno
import os
import urllib

def require_dir(path):
    try:
        os.makedirs(path)
    except OSError, exc:
        if exc.errno != errno.EEXIST:
            raise

directory = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "images")
require_dir(directory)
filename = os.path.join(directory, "stackoverflow.html")

if not os.path.exists(filename):
    urllib.urlretrieve("http://stackoverflow.com", filename)
```

Comment: should the path be /images/ or a full path from the root?

Comment: My example will use a directory called `images` that resides in the same directory as the script file.

Comment: In Python 3 use: `if not os.path.exists(path): os.mkdir(path)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The filename should be in `response.info()['Content-Disposition']` (as a `filename=something` after a semicolon in that string) -- if not (that header is missing, has no semicolon, or has no `filename` part), you can use `urlparse.urlsplit(p.url)` and get the `os.path.basename` of the last non-blank component (or, more pragmatically but that would deeply offend purists, just `p.url.split('/')[-1]` ;-).

So much for the filename, call it e.g. `fn`.

The directory where your script lives is `sd = os.path.dirname(__file__)`.

Its `images` subdirectory is therefore clearly `sdsd = os.path.join(sd, 'images')`.

To check if that subdirectory exists, and make it otherwise,

```
if not os.path.exists(sdsd): os.makedir(sdsd)
```

To check if the file you want to write already exists,

```
if os.path.exists(os.path.join(sdsd, fn)): ...
```

All of this code goes where you have `???`.  It's a lot, so it's clearly better to make it a function taking `p.url` and `response` as arguments (it can read `image` on its own;-) and possibly taking `__file__` as well if you want the freedom to move that function into its own separate module later (I'd recommend that!).

Of course, you need to `import os` for all those `os` and `os.path` calls, and also `import urlparse` if you decide to use the latter standard library module.

Comment: In Python 3 use: `if not os.path.exists(path): os.mkdir(path)` instead.